# Проблемы с открытием проекта в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, установка

Работал в VS2017, на новом пк установил VS2019. Установил все необходимые средства,  но при открытии старого проекта, написанного в VS2017, возникает ошибка что проект предназначен для платформы ".NETFramework, Version=v.4.6.1" и предлагается изменить платформу на ".NET Framework 4.6.1". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]При согласии проект загружается, но не компилируется, тк необходимый ".NETFramework, Version=v.4.6.1" отсутствует. В vs installer установлены все необходимые фреймворки и sdk, но ошибка остается. Видимо, из-за разного написания платформ, хотя это одна и та же версия. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Пробовал изменять версию вручную в конфигурации проекта, но не помогла, опять же сводилось все к версии ".NETFramework, Version=v.4.XXX".

Comment: Похоже в проекте пробел куда-то потерялся в названии фреймворка и из-за этого не может его признать. Детали надо копать, почему так

Comment: visual studio 2019 произошла ошибка открытия окна новый проект что делать
[![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2M9N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2M9N.png)

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, изменив целевую платформу на 4.6.2 в свойствах проекта в самой VS2019. Это помогло, но платформу 4.6.1 оно даже не видит, так что я даже не знаю, в чем может быть причина.